# InvalidOperationException: The entity type <typename> was not found. Ensure that the entity type has been added to the model

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, npgsql

So I'm doing this project in Entity Framework Core with npgsql as my provider. There's a Case class, which is the main class for my solution. With relation one-to-many there's also CaseCustomFieldValue class. Here's the code for them:

```
public class Case
{
    public int CaseId { get; set; }
    public List<CaseCustomFieldValue> CaseCustomFieldValues { get; set; }
}

public class CaseCustomFieldValue
{
    public int CaseCustomFieldValueId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public int CaseId { get; set; }
    public virtual Case Case { get; set; }

}
```

Idea is that CaseCustomFieldValue will be posted/modified/deleted together with the case, but when I'm trying to update value of CaseCustomFieldValue it doesn't change. So I added this into my PUT method:

```
_context.Entry(@case.CaseCustomFieldValues).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

In result above line fails with error:

> InvalidOperationException: The entity type
>   'List<CaseCustomFieldValue>' was      not found. Ensure
>   that the entity type has been added to the model.

I think I did everything needed in DbContext class:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Case>()
            .HasMany(a => a.CaseCustomFieldValues);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Case>().ToTable("Cases");
        modelBuilder.Entity<CaseCustomFieldValue().ToTable("CaseCustomFieldValues");
        public DbSet<Case> Cases { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CaseCustomFieldValue> CaseCustomFieldValues { get; set; }
```

I dropped the database and recreated it from database update, but it didn't help.

Comment: Are you using migrations? Can you see the tables in the db?

Comment: @BarryO'Kane yes and yes :) I could POST the initial value of CaseCustomFieldValue together with the Case, but I can't update it through PUT

Comment: Did you run the add- migration cmdlet after adding the new entity? Add-migration "myMigration"

Comment: Yep, I migrate all the changes

Comment: I just upgraded from ef preview 6 to preview 8 and this issue just started happening too when adding an entity. Maybe downgrade and try again?

Comment: In my case the behavior of abstract classes changed so that the [NotMapped] attribute is no longer required

Comment: It's simple. Nothing to do with migrations or version. `case.CaseCustomFieldValues` is a `List<CaseCustomFieldValue>`. A `List` can never be a mapped entity. You have to handle each `CaseCustomFieldValue` entity individually.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue using the incorrect method to start tracking the model. I was using AddAsync instead of AddRangeAsync for my list of models.

Comment: Having had the same exception isn't relevant. The explanation is what matters.

Answer (score 1):

just check if the object you are passing is a DTO or Entity, people often get confused when they are adding an entity, but end up passing DTO.